# git question : is it better to keep pulling master branch changes into individual dev branch branched out from a feature branch?

Tags: git

this may have been asked before, but i can't find a straight answer and it may be due to having no best answer but here's my scenario:

i have 3 branches:

1. master (latest good code)
2. feature (long running feature branched out from master)
3. a local short lived dev branch (branched out from feature so dev can work on this based on feature branch codes) (let's call it DevX, but there can be many developers each with their own DevX eg Dev1, Dev2, Dev3..)

now, is it a better practice to have DevX also pull changes from master and resolve the conflicts before merging it into feature branch?

or is it better pull the changes from master into feature in another separate merge? (so that DevX changes only reflects DevX changes)

what are your thoughts?

my thought is that it is tempting resolve the master conflicts during DevX branch before going into feature branch so that feature branch is theorically having most parts of the master code but it would require more effort as DevX will need to juggle between master and feature branch codes.

Answer (score 0):

Although I am not well versed with version control, but my views are as below:

As your branching structure is like:

```
    master
      |
   feature
    /  |  \
 dev1 dev2 dev3
```

- As feature is based on master thus in my view you could keep rebasing feature branch from master:

  $ git checkout master // go to master branch

  $ git pull // get its latest from remote

  $ git checkout feature // get back to feature branch

  $ git rebase master // rebase it to get changes of master in feature
- Similarly keep rebasing your dev branches from feature branch before merging dev branches to feature.

  $ git checkout feature // go to feature branch

  $ git pull // get its latest from remote

  $ git checkout devX // get back to dev branch

  $ git rebase feature // rebase it to get changes of feature in dev

So if there is a new commit in master and there is a need of that code in dev branch.
Then rebase feature as shown above and post that rebase dev as shown above and things should be fine I guess.

Post this I guess your merge from dev to feature branch should also work fine.

Side Note: force push local to remote after rebase don't do git pull even if git says to do so, maybe you are already aware of this.